# Customizer chokes on my theme in 4.9, where should I be looking?

Tags: theme-customizer

I upgraded my dev environment to 4.9, and the customizer chokes on my _underscores-based theme. The customizer works fine on TwentySixteen, so I think there is a problem with my theme.

The tell was that the Customizer's Save & Publish button is missing entirely from the UI. Some other strange things happen, like the labels for my settings under the Colors panel are not visible until you click on the color picker.

Firefox dev console says

```
TypeError: a.elements[0] is undefined [Learn More] load-scripts.php:6:12121
```

And when I click [Learn more] it shows

```
<anonymous>
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:6:12121
i
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:27444
fireWith
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:28213
when/<
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:4062
i
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:27444
add
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:27748
when
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:3810
instance
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:2847
f
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:526
<anonymous>
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:6:12068
i
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:27444
fireWith
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:28213
ready
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:30004
K
http://localhost/test-site/wp-admin/load-scripts.php:2:30366
```

The front end seems to be working fine. Is there guidance for theme developers about the changes in the Customizer that 4.9 has delivered? I don't know what I should be looking for.

UPDATE:

I tested this theme on my SiteGround account to make sure the problem wasn't something related to my local machine or server instance. The same issue exists on one of my live sites on SiteGround only after I updated it to 4.9, so I believe this is definitely a problem between my theme and the latest version of WP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the line of code in my theme that is breaking the customizer in 4.9. Behold!

```
$wp_customize->remove_setting( 'header_textcolor' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same error in 4.8.3 if I try just removing the `header_textcolor` setting. So I don't see how this is something new introduced in 4.9. The code that is causing the problem can be found in the [function](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4.9.0/src/wp-admin/js/customize-controls.js#L9035-L9038) that runs for initializing the `display_header_text` control:

```
    // Juggle the two controls that use header_textcolor
    api.control( 'display_header_text', function( control ) {
        var last = '';

        control.elements[0].unsync( api( 'header_textcolor' ) );
```

It's true that this code should be hardened a bit to check for the existence of the `header_textcolor` setting before running, but in the mean time all you need to do is remove the `display_header_text` control in addition to removing the `header_textcolor` setting. Like this:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', function( WP_Customize_Manager $wp_customize ) {
    $wp_customize->remove_setting( 'header_textcolor' );
    $wp_customize->remove_control( 'display_header_text' );
}, 20 );
```

Comment: This is a useful answer, but is not workable in my theme.